# Help to translate signature and chop on scroll of Li River

Tags: translation

Scroll of Li River with signature and chop.
Would like to know what it says or artist.
thank you
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your your help!✨

Answer (score 0):

For the scripts it is:

画 新-on-top-of-旺 年 庚-on-top-of-辰 月 水 山 象

Since in traditional calligraphy, one should read from right to left, top to bottom. It reads as:

象山水月 庚辰年 新旺画

For 象山 You mentioned this is Li river so I assume it is this mountain [象山](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_Trunk_Hill)

For 水月 it is just water and Moon

庚辰年 is some year of dragon, could be 1988 2000 2012( every 12 years).

画 means "draw". So 新旺画 may refer it is drawn by "新旺".
The seal also says 新旺X , hence 新旺 should be the artist's name

I could not recognize the X on the right side of 新旺 in the seal, somebody please help me. Maybe 宝？ but I'm not quite sure.

So all together this is a scroll about the Moon and Water near 象山，drawn by 新旺